# Publishing React Native App using Google Play Assets Delivery

Tags: android, react-native, assets, android-assets

I am currently making an app using React Native which has a lot of assets. Since the app must be offline, I have to make use of Google Play Asset Delivery, but I cannot find a way to make this work with React Native!

Does anyone know how to use Google Play Asset Delivery with a React Native app?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you made any progress with this? I am trying to do this as well.